# I'm using the framework laravel 5.4 , I have 3 tables(users, packs, contacts)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

When i want to code with the relationships(hasMany and belongsTo) I get the error:

QueryException

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contacts.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `contacts` where `contacts`.`user_id` = 2 and `contacts`.`user_id` is not null and `contacts`.`deleted_at` is null)

This is the controller, `ContactController.php`:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Contact;

use Auth;

use App\Http\Requests\contactRequest;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $listcontact = Auth::user()->contacts;

        return view('contact.index', ['lists' => $listcontact]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('contact.create');
    }

            public function store(contactRequest $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact();

        $contact->nom=$request->input('nom');
        $contact->tel=$request->input('tel');
        $contact->genre=$request->input('genre');
        $contact->age=$request->input('age');
        $contact->ville=$request->input('ville');

        $contact->user_idd=Auth::user()->id;

        $contact->save();

        session()->flash('success', 'Contact bien enregistré!!');

        return redirect('contacts');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($id);

        return view('contact.edit', ['cont' => $contact]);
    }

    public function update(contactRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($id);

        $contact->nom = $request->input('nom');
        $contact->tel = $request->input('tel');
        $contact->genre = $request->input('genre');
        $contact->age = $request->input('age');
        $contact->ville = $request->input('ville');

        $contact->save();

        session()->flash('edited', 'Contact bien modifié!!');

        return redirect('contacts');
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $contact = Contact::find($id);

        $contact->delete();

        return redirect('contacts');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is described in your question: "Unknown column 'contacts.user_id". There is no column "user_id" in your "contacts"-table. Additionally there is no reason to search for a special uid and also search for fields where user_id is not null. Only if there are multiple contacts with the same id but then the id is not an unique identifier and you should change your naming

Answer (score 0):

change to $contact->user_idd=Auth::user()->id;

```
$contact->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
```

Comment: thanks , i can't add the other blade and models in order to make you understand the error